# Keep track of worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have about 150 worksheets that I am currently trying to consolidate into one single sheet. I have the following code that I am using

```
Sub Consolidate()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, current As Worksheet, lr As Long, rng As Range, sh As Worksheet
Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
For Each current In Worksheets
   Set sh = Sheets(current.Name)
   lr = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
   Set rng = sh.Range("A9:A" & lr)
   rng.EntireRow.Copy sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2)
Next
End Sub
```

What I want to do is add an entry at the end of each row in order to keep track of which file it came from. That particular information is available on each worksheet.

For example

```
AAA 1 Worksheet1
BBB 2 Worksheet2
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: For one... you have to make sure to exclude `sh1` in your loop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Including @Christmas007's comment:

```
Sub Consolidate()

    Dim sh1 As Worksheet,  lr As Long, rng As Range, sh As Worksheet
    Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")

    For Each sh In Worksheets
       If sh.Name <> sh1.Name Then
       lr = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
       Set rng = sh.Range("A9:A" & lr)
       with sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).offset(1, 0)
           .Resize(rng.rows.count,1).Value = sh.Name
           rng.resize(rng.rows.count, _
                      rng.EntireRow.columns.count-1).Copy .offset(0,1)
       End with

       End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful!

Comment: @tim...Just a quick question....why did you choose columns.count-1? Seems to be skipping 1 column if I understand your code correctly. Thanks

Comment: You were copying the entire column over - can't do that and paste it into the second column, so I resized so it wouldn't be too wide...

Comment: ...of course if you don't really need to copy the whole row then you can just pick some reasonable lesser number of columns to copy.

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit

Sub ConsolidateWorkSheets()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet, rng As Range
    Dim sr As Long, lr As Long, lc As Long

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> ws1.Name Then
            lr = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
            Set rng = ws.Range("A9:A" & ws.Cells(lr, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
            sr = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            rng.EntireRow.Copy ws1.Cells(sr, 1)
            lr = ws1.Cells(ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            lc = ws1.Cells(1, ws1.UsedRange.Columns.Count + 1).End(xlToLeft).Column
            ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(sr, lc + 1), ws1.Cells(lr, lc + 1)).Value2 = ws.Name
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I didn't try your method yet. I may give it a shot once am done with my work. Thanks for the help